# how do I access a variable inside a variable ? (javascript )

Tags: javascript, variables, leaflet

I'm having a bit of a problem here, I'm creating a Leaflet project and need to access to data outside of a variable, in my case a polygon. Until now I have the data inside the polygon with

```
data:[28.63,34.29,12.23,9.33,6.97,3.93,4.63]
```

but I'd prefer the data to be outside of this variable with

```
var koeln = [28.63,34.29,12.23,9.33,6.97,3.93,4.63];
```

I'm now looking for a result how to access to the var koeln inside of the data, I've tried to put it in brakes or other things, but nothing seems to work..

edit:

```
  var wahl2017 =  { "type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [ { "type": "Feature", "properties": 
        {"name":"Wahlbezirk 13","partei":"cdu","wahlbeteiligung":69.42, "drittpa1":"gruen","drittpa2":"fdp", data:[28.63,34.29,12.23,9.33,6.97,3.93,4.63],title:"Köln I"}, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [6.976650953292847, 50.84119137806263 ],
```

(and so on)

Comment: `var koeln = someObj.data`?

Comment: pls share more code

Answer (score 1):

Refering to your comment, you have this data structure:

```
var wahl2017 = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "name": "Wahlbezirk 13",
            "partei": "cdu",
            "wahlbeteiligung": 69.42,
            "drittpa1": "gruen",
            "drittpa2": "fdp",
            data: [28.63, 34.29, 12.23, 9.33, 6.97, 3.93, 4.63],
            title: "Köln I"
        }
    }]
};
```

You can access the data like this:

```
let koeln = wahl2017.features[0].properties.data
```

Comment: sorry I must have written my question wrong, I want the data to be in the let koeln variable instead of the var wahl2017

Answer (score 0):

You can access the data variables with `var koeln = wahl2017.features[0].properties.data`

When you have more cities you can call `.forEach()`

```
var cities = [];
wahl2017.features.forEach(function(city){
    cities.push({name: city.properties.name, data: city.properties.data});
})

console.log(cities);
console.log(cities[0].data);
```

Comment: sorry I must have written my question wrong, I want the data to be in the let koeln variable instead of the var wahl2017

Comment: yes, your data are in wahl2017 already and you want to have the data in the variable koeln (from wahl2017, or what where is your data source?). My code does this...

Comment: i apologize, I want to remove the data from wahl2017 and have it instead In a single variable ( var koeln ). and my problem is that I don't know, what to code in wahl2017 data: , when all the data is in var koeln

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208991/how-do-i-access-a-variable-inside-a-variable-javascript let us chat here